# Dashed circular arcs not created in texmaker

Tags: pstricks, circles

I am trying to run the following sample codes, containing PStricks codes generated by Geogebra, in Texmaker in the sequence Latex+dvips+ps2pdfviewpdf (in Ubuntu).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}%NICe
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=white!100}%}, fg=black!100}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{Sample}
 \begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{center}
 \psscalebox{0.5 0.5} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
  {
 \newrgbcolor{xdxdff}{0.49 0.49 1}
 \psset{xunit=0.5cm,yunit=0.5cm,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-7.96,-11.79)(40.22,11.47)
\psline(-4,8)(-2,10)
\psline(-4,8)(-6,10)
\psline(-4,8)(-6,6)
\psline(-4,8)(-2,6)
\psline(-4,8)(-6.83,7.99)
\psline(-4,8)(-1.24,8.02)
\parametricplot[linestyle=dashed,dash=4pt 4pt]{3.145209626861558}{3.9269908169872414}{1*2.83*cos(t)+0*2.83*sin(t)+-4|0*2.83*cos(t)+1*2.83*sin(t)+8}
\parametricplot[linestyle=dashed,dash=4pt 4pt]{2.356194490192345}{3.145209626861558}{1*2.83*cos(t)+0*2.83*sin(t)+-4|0*2.83*cos(t)+1*2.83*sin(t)+8}
\parametricplot[linestyle=dashed,dash=4pt 4pt]{0.00766901039872073}{0.7853981633974483}{1*2.76*cos(t)+0*2.76*sin(t)+-4|0*2.76*cos(t)+1*2.76*sin(t)+8}
\parametricplot[linestyle=dashed,dash=4pt 4pt]{-0.7853981633974483}{0.00766901039872073}{1*2.83*cos(t)+0*2.83*sin(t)+-4|0*2.83*cos(t)+1*2.83*sin(t)+8}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But I get an error and the dashed circular arcs are not created.
The following error comes :

`Undefined control sequence \parametricplot
   l.510 \end{frame}`

Comment: Your code is unfinished and can't be compiled.

Comment: oh sorry .. that was a mistake .. let me correct it

Comment: @Bernard .. I have edited. Is it working with you now ?

Comment: No, but there's something special with your code: why do you use `|` to separate x(t) from y(t)? Moreover, there's a problem with algebraic notation. I'll post my answer in moment. Do you really need that all those decimals, or is due to a software conversion to pstricks?

Comment: Oh .. actually I have generated the codes using Geogebra and the "|" (bar) got generated automatically,.

Comment: I think you should simplify your expressions. I'll give (commented)  simplified expressions.

Answer (score 1):

As there's `no  place for a new dimension` problem with beamer, I use the `standalone` class. You can then use an `\includegraphics` command. Here is a simplified code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, x11names, pdf]{standalone}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

 \newrgbcolor{xdxdff}{0.49 0.49 1}
 \psset{unit=0.25cm,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25, algebraic}%
\begin{pspicture*}(-7.96,-11.79)(40.22,11.47)%
\psline(-4,8)(-2,10)
\psline(-4,8)(-6,10)
\psline(-4,8)(-6,6)
\psline(-4,8)(-2,6)
\psline(-4,8)(-6.83,7.99)
\psline(-4,8)(-1.24,8.02)
\psset{linecolor = red, linestyle=dashed,dash=4pt 4pt, arrows = c-c }
\parametricplot{3.145209626861558}{3.9269908169872414}{1*2.83*cos(t)+0*2.83*sin(t) +-4|

0*2.83*cos(t)+1*2.83*sin(t)+8}
    \parametricplot{2.356194490192345}{3.145209626861558}{1*2.83*cos(t)+0*2.83*sin(t)+-4|0*2.83*cos(t)+1*2.83*sin(t)+8}
    \parametricplot{0.00766901039872073}{0.7853981633974483}{1*2.76*cos(t)+0*2.76*sin(t)+-4|0*2.76*cos(t)+1*2.76*sin(t)+8}
    \parametricplot{-0.7853981633974483}{0.00766901039872073}{1*2.83*cos(t)+0*2.83*sin(t)+-4|0*2.83*cos(t)+1*2.83*sin(t)+8}
%    \parametricplot{3.145}{3.927}{2.83*cos(t)-4|2.83sin(t) + 8}
%    \parametricplot{3.145}{3.927}{2.83*cos(t)-4|2.83sin(t) + 8}
%    \parametricplot{0.008}{0.785}{2.76*cos(t)-4|2.76*sin(t)+8}
%    \parametricplot{-0.785}{0.008}{2.83*cos(t)-4|2.83*sin(t)+8}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

there are some missing parameters. This runs with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}%NICe
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=white!100}%}, fg=black!100}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Sample}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{0.6\linewidth}{!}{%
 \psset{xunit=0.5cm,yunit=0.5cm,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture}(-7,6)(-1,10)
\psline(-4,8)(-2,10)
\psline(-4,8)(-6,10)
\psline(-4,8)(-6,6)
\psline(-4,8)(-2,6)
\psline(-4,8)(-6.83,7.99)
\psline(-4,8)(-1.24,8.02)
\psset{algebraic,linestyle=dashed,dash=4pt 4pt}
\parametricplot{3.145209626861558}{3.9269908169872414}{1*2.83*cos(t)+0*2.83*sin(t)+-4|0*2.83*cos(t)+1*2.83*sin(t)+8}
\parametricplot{2.356194490192345}{3.145209626861558}{1*2.83*cos(t)+0*2.83*sin(t)+-4|0*2.83*cos(t)+1*2.83*sin(t)+8}
\parametricplot{0.00766901039872073}{0.7853981633974483}{1*2.76*cos(t)+0*2.76*sin(t)+-4|0*2.76*cos(t)+1*2.76*sin(t)+8}
\parametricplot{-0.7853981633974483}{0.00766901039872073}{1*2.83*cos(t)+0*2.83*sin(t)+-4|0*2.83*cos(t)+1*2.83*sin(t)+8}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks ! But I can't understand why it doesn't work in my system. It gives the same error message again. And when I compile it without the pst-plot package, it runs but the dashed arcs are not produced.

Comment: The same code works fine in article class but it does not work at all in beamer class.

Comment: How do you run it in beamer? `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` or `xelatex` or???

Comment: ya i use to run it as latex-dvips-ps2pdf

Comment: then the above example should be no problem. What does your error message say??

Comment: not exactly an error. It runs but it does not display the dashed arcs.

Comment: run the example with `xelatex`. What happens?

Comment: is there any option to run xelatex in texmaker ?

Comment: it should be available via the compile button. Or define it with `User->Commands->Define`

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on the code generated by Geogebra as it wastes many keystrokes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\def\radius{3 }
\def\angle{45 }

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-\radius,-\radius)(\radius,\radius)
    \multido{\i=1+-1}{3}{\psline(!\radius \i\space \angle mul 180 add PtoC)(!\radius \i\space \angle mul PtoC)}
    \multido{\i=0+1}{2}{\psarc[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red](0,0){\radius}{!-\angle 180 \i\space mul add}{!\angle 180 \i\space mul add}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]